# How to solve problem with nojump object, that has to jump?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have problem with my code, I´ve started learn C#, so I tried code some game(something like Geometry Dash). I want that move and on click jump. I wrote "move code" and "onclick jump code" but isn´t working.

I´m writing in Microsoft Visual Studio in C# and design in Unity 2018.3.5f1.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Plaxercontrol2 : MonoBehaviour
{
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public Transform groundCheck;
public Transform startPosition;
public float groundCheckRadius;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
private bool onGround;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(3, rb.velocity.y);
    onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 
groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && onGround)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(5, rb.velocity.x);
    }

}
}
```

Now, it´s only moving

and picture of Unity
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of changing yourself the velocity, I'm pretty sure you should use `rb.AddForce()` or something similar. That is how you're supposed to move rigid bodies.

You could do something like:

```
rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * whatEverValue, ForceMode2D.Impulse)
```

Comment: What is not working ? If you get any error please show. What values did you try for whatEverValue ? Try 1, 10, 100, 1000. Adding force depends of the mass of your rigibody, so you may tweak values to get what you want

Comment: Are you sure that it is executed ? Try adding a Debug.Log() just before rb.AddForce() to see if it goes there, because it should work

Comment: And how to add Debug.Log()? I am begginner

Comment: if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && onGround)
    {
        Debug.Log("we added force !");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(5, rb.velocity.x);
    }

Comment: It´s doing nothing, but i noticed warning in Unity: UnassignedReferenceException: The variable groundCheck of Plaxercontrol2 has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the groundCheck variable of the Plaxercontrol2 script in the inspector.

Comment: It's not a warning but an error, and that is why it's not working. Just drag and drop your gameobject into the field groundCheck in your inspector and it should be working ;)